# can i play with node.js on a web based console?

Tags: node.js

I have a temporary situation whereby I am unable to install node on my computer. Is there a web based lightweight terminal I can play with and learn node by doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check out [cloud9](http://c9.io), they offer a whole development environment (also for JavaScript - node.js).

Comment: thanks! I signed up but keeps crashing when I try to start a new node.js project...hmm...

Comment: This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://c9.io is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: I just tried it myself and it worked without any problem.. So after you click on "create workspace" you immediately see this error?

Comment: hmm I don't know the answer for that behaviour, sorry - maybe try another browser, it might not be an error on the side of c9..

or maybe their docs can help you out on that: https://docs.c9.io/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

NPM uses RunKit for this purpose. You can use all of the packages available on NPM and its free too. https://runkit.com/home

Comment: thanks...so I signed up for this, I create a new workbook, but I am unable to type anything into the input console...very strange

Comment: Hey! I checked the service right now and it works fine! Maybe check again?